# How to consume https api from asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4, https

I have an asp net mvc project using vs2019, my controller is:

```
namespace EJM_MATRICULA.Controllers
{
    public class SunatController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My index.cshtml is like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<label>type data: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtDni" />
<input type="button" id="btnBuscar" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success" />
<div id="tabla">
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mydata.js"></script>
```

Finally mydata.js contains this code:

```
var btnBuscar = document.getElementById("btnBuscar");
btnBuscar.onclick = function () {
    var dni = document.getElementById("txtDni").value;
    $.get("https://api.sunat.cloud/ruc/" + dni, function (data) {
        showdata(["RUC", "RAZSOC"], data);
    });
}
```

It's my first time using an https api, should I set anything?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you execute your code now, do you get an error? Can you elaborate on "should I set anything"?

Comment: I don't get an error, no appear anything. When i run on the browser it return a json. https://api.sunat.cloud/ruc/06915398 try it with this example.